# Padding and text alignment issue

Tags: c#

I have a little problem aligning my text. Here is what I am trying to do with example:

```
******************************************
*                                        *
* Shoes                                  *
*       10xx       75.00        750.00 A *
* Shirt                                  *
*       100xx      100.00     10000.00 A *  
*                                        *
******************************************
```

(note that the total price with the A at the end is aligned according to the A and the rest is aligned according to the first number, dots * are borders of a paper)

here is code:

```
graphic.DrawString(" " + item[i].ToString() + "".PadRight(30), font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
                    offset = offset + 22;
                    stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;

graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(17) + quantity[i].ToString() + " xx" + "".PadRight(17) + " " + price.ToString("n2") + "".PadRight(12) + totalPrice.ToString("n2") + " A".PadRight(10), font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
```

but what I am getting is messed up and not aligned

Comment: What are you aligning this in? PadLeft/Right only really works  for monospaced fonts

Comment: You will only get aligned text if you use a monospaced font

Comment: Use Consolas or Courier! For proportional fonts you need to draw each string separately and calculate their positions after measuring their sizes..